# Database functions mapped to ActiveRecord Models

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, stored-procedures, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Let's suppose I have two database functions like this (pl/pgsql):

```
CREATE TABLE balances (rents decimal(12,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        expenses decimal(12,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
CREATE FUNCTION account_balance(id integer)
        RETURNS balances AS $$
        SELECT
          SUM(CASE WHEN t.amount > 0 THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) as rents,
          SUM(CASE WHEN t.amount < 0 THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) as expenses
        FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.account_id = $1
      $$ language 'sql';
CREATE FUNCTION tenant_balance(id integer)
      RETURNS balances AS $$
      SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.amount > 0 THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) as rents,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.amount < 0 THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) as expenses
      FROM transactions t
      WHERE t.tenant_id = $1
    $$ language 'sql';
```

How could I relate to this in my ActiveRecord models (in this examples, Account and Tenant) so I can call something like `Account.first.balance` and it returns a valid instance of Balance?
Speaking of Balance, how should I create this model?

Comment: I'd suggest you check out DockYard's postgres_ext gem, it will give you ability to work with CTEs nicely right from ActiveRecord. https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext